# ASP.net where to add assembly to web.config while only compiling dll?

Tags: asp.net, dll, web-config

I need to compile a class library (DLL) from an ASP.NET source. Now when I try to build it says this:

> The type
>   'System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize'
>   is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference
>   to assembly 'System, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Now I know that I have to put it in the web.config file. But there is no web.config file it's just the source of the dll that needs to be compiled.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the directions in the error message and add a reference to the `System.dll` assembly in your class library project.

Right-click on your project, select `Add Reference...` in the context menu, then choose the `System` entry in the `.NET` tab.

Comment: I'd agree, except isn't System always included by default?

Comment: @Rup, by default, yes, but it looks like @baklap has removed the default references from his project. `System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize` is present in all .NET versions, so I don't think there's a mismatch there.